# Traveling to Mexico via land - problem when coming back to the US?

Tags: usa, esta, mexico

I had planned a flight to Indonesia out of the US, but plans changed and we went to Mexico instead. I heard that when you go to Mexico by land it doesn't tell the US border system that you left the country... does this mean it might say I overstayed next time I come back on my ESTA VWP visa?

I will be staying for more than 3 months in Mexico and then I have a flight leaving from San Francisco, which will make me enter the US again, will I have a problem?

Comment: To clarify, you traveled to US on ESTA, drove into Mexico, will be in Mexico for more than 90 days before trying to re-enter the US by land?  I would think it **is** likely you will have issues trying to re-enter

Comment: That's right.. just going back to the US to catch a flight...

Comment: How did your plans work, were you able to get back into the US without issue?

Comment: OP has not returned to answer comments :/ Putting on hold.